# Remote shutdown bat for multiple machines gives error on only a few

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I recently started messing around with a .BAT file to remote shut down a computer lab.
I have the file to where it will shutdown almost everyone of the machines flawlessly, but a few of them will give an error. Sadly, I did not take note of it, but I believe it had "53" after it. It stated something about the machine not supporting remote shutdown or not having administrative rights.
I started the BAT from an administrator acct., and each PC in the lab was imaged with the same image. The BAT worked fine for almost every machine except a few. I checked each failed machine and they did not have any programs open that would require user feedback to close.

I used the same line for all 20 machines only changing the number after LAB

Here's what I came up with:

`ECHO Shutdown`

`C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe  /s /m \\HES-LAB-01`

`PAUSE`

Any feedback would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the pass-through authentication is failing for some reason.  Odd since they are all from the same image.  In any case, you could do a `net use \\HES-LAB-xx /user:username` first.  If the user exists on all machines with the same password you won't have to add the password to the `net use` command.  Then the shutdown will likely not fail.  Or use `psshutdown` from http://sysinternals.com (now owned by Microsoft) -- it fixes a lot of the unexplainable issues with `shutdown.exe`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out as soon as I can and let you know!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks James and @Bambi

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\User>net helpmsg 53

The network path was not found.
```

Presumably the server specified doesn't exist or not turned on